# Multiple Yii2 dataProviders for a single grid view

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

Do any one knows a way to load a yii2 gridview with multiple activeDataProviders?

Comment: You can have only one dataProvider  for gridView  ..

Comment: I am getting data from multiple tables, I collected them in a single arrayDataProvider, but I am working on filtering. I found this solution as a turn around. But still need filtering... THANKS FOR YOUR COMMENT.

Comment: For filtering you must iimplement   a proper seach function ...  you post the query for dataProvider  and the search function you think to use  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used multiple arrays of data, then array_merge($arr1, $arr2,...) and pass the resultant array to an arrayDataProvider.